# mongodb update or insert sub-array

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, sub-array

ok, I need away to do the following

I have the mongo collect as

```
array (
  '_id' => new MongoId("50513d8338fc5de706000000"),
  'offers' => 
  array (
    '0' => 
    array (
      'minspend' => '50.00',
      'cashback' => '1.50',
      'percentage' => '0.03',
    ),
    '1' => 
    array (
      'minspend' => '100.00',
      'cashback' => '3.00',
      'percentage' => '0.03',
    ),
  ),
  'percentageTotal' => '0.06',
  'test' => new MongoInt32(1),
)
```

but lets say I want to update only this part

```
array (
        '0' => 
        array (
          'minspend' => '50.00',
          'cashback' => '1.50',
          'percentage' => '0.03',
        ),
```

what is the best way to change that part of the sub array without re-creating the whole collection of data in that array.

and is it possible to do something like this

```
array (
        '0' => 
        array (
'Offer_id'=> new MongoId(5715671561715),
          'minspend' => '50.00',
          'cashback' => '1.50',
          'percentage' => '0.03',
        ),
```

)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `$set` together with dot-notation to specify which element of an array you want to update:

```
$collection->update(
    array("_id" => new MongoId("50513d8338fc5de706000000")), 
    array("$set" => array("offers.0" => 
        array (
            'minspend' => '50.00',
            'cashback' => '1.50',
            'percentage' => '0.03',
        )
    ))
);
```

`offers.0` refers to the 0th (= first) element in the array. If you want to update the second one, you would use `offers.1` as the key.

For your second question, I'm assuming you want to add the MongoId to the sub-document. You can do that the same way, simply by adding `'Offer_id' => new MongoId(),` before minspend. This will create a new unique MongoId and add it to the sub-document. If you want to add an existing MongoId instead, use `new MongoId("...")` and replace the `...` with the 24 hexidecimal character long string.

If you already have an Offer_id and only want to change the offer that matches that id, you can use the positional $ syntax:

```
$collection->update(
    array("_id" => new MongoId("50513d8338fc5de706000000"),
          "offers.Offer_id" => new MongoId("5059637720dfeda164ec0fe7")), 

    array("$set" => array("offers.$" => 
        array (
            'minspend' => '50.00',
            'cashback' => '1.50',
            'percentage' => '0.03',
        )
    ))
);
```

You query for the document with the correct `_id` and additionally for the `offers.Offer_id`. In the update part of the command, you use `offers.$` where $ will automatically match the correct sub-document that contains the Offer_id.

Comment: if i have the offers.[].offer_id can i use that to update the minspend etc?

Comment: In that case, use the offer_id in the query as a second condition (querying for _id and offers.offer_id and use the $ sign as the positional argument. See here how the positional operator works: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-The%24positionaloperator

Comment: could you please explain this? with an example the documents dont really help

Comment: sure, I've added it to the code example above. I hope this answers your question.